# How do you toggle a single div visibility with two different click events based on variable?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with 3 items (A,B,C items, lets say checkout form).

Two of them A and B are physical items(shipping address collection), and one is digital (no shipping, and no subject here)

I want to extend the form based on selection in a way that when user opt for A, B or both, the button leading to next step of the form is shown, and submit button is hidden.

I did tried some code, which worked if A or B are selected, but since I'm using .toggle, obviously if A is selected already (and showing Next button) and you select the B, it will be toggled back between them.

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="itemA" checked>A (physical)</input>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="itemB">B (physical</input>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="itemC">C (digital)</input>

<input name="order-button" id="order-button" type="submit" />
<input name="next" id="next" type="button" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#itemA').change(function () {
      $('#next').toggle('slow');
      $('#order-button').toggle('slow');
    })

    $('#itemB').change(function () {
      $('#next').toggle('slow');
      $('#order-button').toggle('slow');
    })
});
</script>
```

So how do I toggle buttons respectively if either A, B or both items are checked? (When A is selected B should never toggle and vice versa)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a variable which store the current state of your form:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Assuming the default option is A or B, we want to show the #next button
    var showNextButton = true; 

    $('#itemA, #itemB').change(function () {
      // Only trigger toggles if #next was hidden
      if (!showNextButton) {
        $('#next').toggle('slow');
        $('#order-button').toggle('slow');
        showNextButton = true;
      }
    });

    $('#itemC').change(function () {
      // Only trigger toggles if #next was visible
      if (showNextButton) {
        $('#next').toggle('slow');
        $('#order-button').toggle('slow');
        showNextButton = false;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Damn vars :) (I actually need none to be checked and to show the button next only when A or B are selected, but I can work around that with the answer you gave. Cheers!